# Optimizing a summation of a series (using loops and recursion) (answered in comments)

Tags: c++, loops, recursion, optimization

I need to do a summation of series that works as follows: 1+2+3+4+5+.....+n

where 'n' follows this range:  ( 1 ≤ N ≤ 10^9 )

The 1 rule I have to follow is that it should never take too long as I shove my code into a testing site that tries several test values and compares the output of my code with it's own output under a proper time limit

The approach of using n * (n+1) / 2 works fine but I'd like to know the harder alternatives (Thanks to the comment section for the equation)

I initially used recursion

```
int recur( int n )
{
 if (n > 0) {
        return n + recur( n - 1 ) ;
    } else {
        return 0 ;
    }
}

int main()
{
 int n ;
 cin >> n ;
 cout << recur(n) ;
}
```

This approach failed on the upper half of the range of 'n' making an exception so i did a loop and to speed up that loop i made an if statement to perform the recursion on the lower half of the range and the actual loop on the upper half

here's the full code

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int recur( int n )
{
 if (n > 0) {
        return n + recur( n - 1 ) ;
    } else {
        return 0 ;
    }
}

void verylong( int n )
{
long long sum = 0;
for( int i = 0 ; i <= n ; i++ )
{
 sum += i ;
}
cout << sum ;
}

int main()
{
 int n ;
 cin >> n ;
 if( n < 10000 ){
    cout << recur(n) ;
 }
 else{
    verylong(n) ;
 }
}
```

Now the results are correct but this runs visibly slow on the maximum number within range, how can improve this? is there a better approach overall? what is that approach?

Note: I have seen some other posts approach this using unrolling but I don't know how to unroll a simple series like this without butchering the result

Edit: Purely looping this in general is inefficient according to the comments so this is technically answered

Comment: Isn't it allowed to simply do `n * (n + 1) / 2`?

Comment: Prefer not to use recursion for summation.  Summation is a simple `for` loop.  Recursion requires a lot of stack spaces and IMHO, is slower than a `for` loop.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I am trying to cut off every microsecond I can

Comment: @MikeCAT I can, and I did to complete my assignment but I want to know how loops and recursions can be used in this context and output results as quickly as possible, maybe I'll leave this post having learned a thing or two that isn't the same concept as duff's device or simplifying the summation into a single equation

Comment: Usually, the online *puzzles* require an optimized or obscure algorithm in order to resolve a Time Limit Exceeded (TLE) error.  Optimizing for milliseconds is not enough.

Comment: @Star -- If you got this question from an online coding website, please note that the questions on those sites are designed so that there are easy, naive solutions that will *never* pass the time-limit-exceeded threshold.  Those questions are designed for you to find a smarter algorithm, or in this case, the closed formula to come up with the results.  Looping a billion times is never a good solution.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews You are correct but I believe it works fast enough when it doesn't repeat itself too much, The main issue happens on the large numbers with the loop
(sorry about commenting twice, the site didn't let me edit)

Comment: @Star To be honest, I don't see what goal you're trying to accomplish.  In the real world, you would never call a recursive routine a maximum of 10^9 times, and you would certainly try to figure out a way to not loop 10^9 times.  The "answer" to the particular sum formula was already given.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Well, yes, I do still want to know a little about the hard path to get there though, if there is a possible one.
"Looping a billion times is never a good solution" mhm, I can see that, what would be a good solution though without these naive approaches?

Comment: It depends on the problem.  If it were one where you need to search a billion items, you would sort them (using a good sorting algorithm) and then use binary search.  If it were to get the top K items in a billion items, you use a min-heap of K instead of storing all of those items in memory.  If it's mathematics related, you come up with a closed formula, etc.  What you should never do is attempt to write code that yes, will work on a few hundred values, but for a billion or so values, it is a non-starter writing such a loop.

Comment: So optimizing mathematical questions can't really be done in the same manner as other problems with coming up with a closed formula being my best bet? @PaulMcKenzie

Comment: Either a closed formula, or for something like computing Fibonacci numbers, "mathematical tricks" like Binets formula to compute large Fibonacci numbers can be done.  The bottom line is that all of those questions you see on those sites that deal with math, the author of those questions know beforehand that there is a closed formula, or a formula that gets close to the real solution, and then some simple secret sauce to get to the exact answer.  There is no way you would get a question where the only way to get to the answer is to loop an umpteen number of times.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind then, good to know and thanks.
I'll have to look into the Fibonacci numbers and Binets formula you talked about, That leaves it answered.

Comment: A `for` loop will allow you to apply some optimizations like loop unrolling and operating in parallel.  Parallel computing is more complex when using recursion.